# Move FF "Find Toolbar" to top

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Is there a way to move the "Find Toolbar" in Firefox from the bottom to the top of the window?

[image: firefox find toolbar]

Answer (score 3):

There is an [add-on for the find-bar that lets you customise it](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/find-toolbar-tweaks).

Alternatively, a bit of CSS hack can do it ...

Try:

```
#FindToolbar { 

  position: fixed !important;

  border: 0px solid transparent;

  border-top: none; 

  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

  background: inherit;

  top:48px;

  left:2px;

  background-position: 78% -40px;

  }
```

But this can have some issues, moving other elements round the UI.

Comment: looks like you're missing the last s from that URL: find-toolbar-tweaks.

Comment: Good sport. Amended.

Comment: "As usual, Find toolbar code has changed between 3.6 and 4, so "Find Toolbar on Top" function was dropped on 3.0.0." <<- From the author of the add-on

Comment: Where would I put the css snippet?

Comment: You can customise FF in the userchrome file. See [the following](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html). Could you edit your answer to specify the version of FF?

Comment: With the new versioning scheme Mozilla has what version I have is soon going to change but it's 5.0 today...

Comment: The link you posted in your comment points to a stale website, do you have a better resource?. From website **You are currently viewing a snapshot of www.mozilla.org taken on April 21, 2008. Most of this content is highly out of date**

Comment: Sorry, I was unsure of your ff version, and they have changed, slightly, how to edit the style sheet from version to version. If you are on Win then the userchrome.css is inC:\Users\[yourusername]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[profile.default]\chrome. If there is no userchrome.CSS you will need to create one, use the namespace ....  @namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* only needed once */

Answer (score 1):

There is a modern extension [FindBar Tweak](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/findbar-tweak/) that allows this and is neatly integrated with recent Firefox versions.